# What is the name of this modified Gaussian?

Tags: statistics, functions, probability-distributions

I am reading a paper that defines

$$ \mathcal{T}(x, \mu, \sigma) = A \cdot x \cdot \exp \left \{ - \left[ \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} + \frac{\sigma}{2 \mu} \right]^2 \right \}.$$

It is introduced in order to have a Gaussian that goes to zero at $x=0$. It says that $A$ has to be chosen such that $\mathcal{T}$ is "unimodular". I am not sure how to calculate $\mathcal T$ because I am unsure how to find $A$. So my questions are: how can I find $A$, and is there a name for $\mathcal T$?

Comment: Is this limited to x>=0? I presume this is some form of probability distribution, in which case A is fixed by normalising to 1.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments $A$ has to be chosen such that the density finally integrates to $1$.
Also to ensure that the density stays positive we further need $x \geq 0$.
To find $A$ we first pick $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a > 0$ to calculate (or asking Wolfram Alpha for help)
\begin{align*}
I(a,b) = \int_0^{\infty} x \exp\left(-\left(\frac{x - b}{a}\right)^2\right) dx = \frac{a}{2} \left(a e^{-b^2/a^2} + b\sqrt{\pi}\left( \mbox{erf}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) + 1\right)\right), 
\end{align*}
where $\mbox{erf}$ is the error function.
Now taking a look at the exponent in the exponential you can see that
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma} + \frac{\sigma}{2\mu}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{x}{\sigma} - \frac{1}{\sigma}\left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu}\right)\right)^2 = \left(\frac{x-\left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu}\right)}{\sigma} \right)^2,
\end{align*}
i.e. we can pick $a = \sigma$ and $b = \mu - \sigma^2 / (2\mu)$ to calculate $A = 1 / I(a,b)$.

I can't help with the name for this density, also the word "unimodular" somehow does not fit in this context (in my opinion).